# What data types to store db2 xml in java?

Tags: java, xml, jdbc, db2

I have a requirement to get XML data stored in db2. In db2 the XML data is stored in a table column whose type is XML (db2).

Now if i have to retrieve it using plain JDBC (no other choice i have here), what is the java data type in which this should be mapped.

From what i researched, i feel it should be this way.

```
String xmlData = (String) resultSet.getObject(1);
```

(assuming 1 is the column index where the xml data is stored)

Is this a viable solution? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ResultSet` has `getSQLXML(int)` which returns a `java.sql.SQLXML` object.
[SQLXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLXML.html) gives you the most options to access the XML data.

Anyway you have a wide variety of options to retrieve the XML.
According this [doc](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_c0021817.html) you can simply use `ResultSet.getString(int)` if you want the data as String.

But as always it depends on the version of your DB2 and your JDBC driver if all these options are supported.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Does getString() provide the xml data as it is? Like if xml has some special characters, will that be as it is?

Comment: @Vicky: The getString() should respect encodings. But its best to experiment. Just try and see what DB2 returns.